# Using ExceptionFilterAttribute in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement the error handling in the created Web API, need to return the exception details in JSON format. I created the BALExceptionFilterAttribute like

```
public class BALExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
        actionExecutedContext.Response = actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { error = actionExecutedContext.Exception.Message });
    }
}
```

And registered them in Gloal.asax.cs like

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new BALExceptionFilterAttribute());
```

In my Controllers I want to throw the exception like

```
    [HttpGet]
    [BALExceptionFilter]
    public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails(string ROOM, DateTime DOB_GT)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ROOM) 
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(new { error = "Input paramete cannot be Empty or NULL" });
        }
            //throws the exception
            throw new BALExceptionFilterAttribute();

            List<OracleParameter> prms = new List<OracleParameter>();
            List<string> selectionStrings = new List<string>();
            prms.Add(new OracleParameter("ROOM", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ROOM, ParameterDirection.Input));
            prms.Add(new OracleParameter("DOB_GT", OracleDbType.Date, DOB_GT, ParameterDirection.Input));
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TGSDataBaseConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
            {
                DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
                var strQuery = "SELECT * from LIMS_SAMPLE_RESULTS_VW where ROOM = :ROOM and DOB > :DOB_GT ";
                var returnObject = new { data = new OracleDataTableJsonResponse(connStr, strQuery, prms.ToArray()) };
                var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
                ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
                if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=TGSData.json", out contentDisposition))
                {
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
                }
                return response;
               }
        }
```

But it shows error like  on the `throw new BALExceptionFilterAttribute();`
`Error  1   The type caught or thrown must be derived from System.Exception`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//throws the exception
throw new BALExceptionFilterAttribute();
```

That will generate a compiler error. The exception filter attribute is to do something in the event of an exception so you can handle it in a generic manner like redirecting to an error page or sending back a generic exception message in the json response, etc. **The exception filter attribute itself is not an exception, it handles the exception.**

So `throw new BALExceptionFilterAttribute();` is not valid because `BALExceptionFilterAttribute` is not an exception.

If you want a `BALException` type then create one.

```
public class BALException : Exception { /* add properties and constructors */}
```

and now you can throw it

```
throw new BALException();
```

and then you can configure `BALExceptionFilterAttribute` to do something in the event that this exception reaches the filter (is not caught in the controller).

Answer (score 2):

`ExceptionFilterAttribute` inherits from `System.Attribute` not `System.Exception`.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.exceptionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Why you don't get a compiler error I am not so sure.

**EDIT**

A filter allows you to hook into the ASP.NET pipeline at various points to write code that handles events. Exception handling is a good example of that.

If you need a custom exception as well then you can create an extra class for example `public class BALException : Exception` although looking at your use case as described you may well be able to use an existing framework exception.

I am at all clear as to why you want to throw it in the normal execution of you work flow as written in the original post.

Comment: Yes it does throw the compiler error. How do I deal with this