# Does an uncaught exception terminate the whole ASP.NET Core webapp?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose I have a method that calls a database but for some reason there is an exception thrown.

In the event that I do not catch that exception in my ASP.NET Core page, will the whole webapp crash or just that page cannot be fully loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific example, just the page requested that leads to the database call will fail. If the exception occurs elsewhere in the pipeline, then the whole app may no longer work.

Take a look at this answer: [Using ExceptionFilterAttribute in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743241/using-exceptionfilterattribute-in-web-api/40743435#40743435)

for more info on exception handling in .net core